# Jquery toggle not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following jquery script is not working in firefox. Anyone with a idea on how to correct it?

```
$(document).ready(function () {    

$('#all_lists').hide();

$('#add_lists').click( function(){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('#all_lists').toggle();
});

$(document).click( function(){
    $('#all_lists').hide();
});

});
```

Comment: You need to pass `event` in the click function like `$('#add_lists').click( function(event){`

Comment: In your `#add_lists` click-handler, add `event` argument to the function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to pass `event` as an argument in the click function like:

```
$('#add_lists').click( function(event){
                                ^   ^
```

Answer (score 3):

javascript:jQuery('body').toggleClass('open');

Using JS on an image map was returning [object, Object] in a new window in Firefox only.  Fixed with:

javascript:jQuery('body').toggleClass('open');**void(0);**